# Any python framework to make auto posting/tasking?

Tags: python, facebook, web, browser, frameworks

So currently, I need to write a tool to open web browser (like firefox) and then go to some specific links/forums in order to post a topic (like an auto post tool). I also want to post on facebook groups. However, I have no clue where to start to make this automatic tool. Is there any python framework out there that can help me write this tool?

Thanks.

Comment: selenium might be a good place to start ... or pywinauto ... maybe some others .... people might get mad at you though just fyi

Comment: Use the Facebook API to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium can help you to do something automatic in browser, here is an 
example to login google.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def Login_Google(browser, category_root_address):

  browser.get(category_root_address)

  # click to login
  login_link = browser.find_element_by_id('gb_70')
  webdriver.ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(login_link).click(login_link).perform()

  # input your email here
  email = browser.find_element_by_name('Email')
  # you should input your email here
  email.send_keys('') 

  # input your password here
  pwd = browser.find_element_by_name('Passwd')
  # you should input your password for your email here
  pwd.send_keys('')
  pwd.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

  print 'Login Success'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  root_address = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/TRAVEL_AND_LOCAL?hl=en'

  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  Login_Google(driver, root_address)
```